# while connect to firebase get NameError: name 'request' is not defined

Tags: python, firebase, urllib

I have a final project so i need some help for showing the temperature sensor with firebase, I am using Raspberry Pi B+ and a DS18B20 sensor, i wrote all the commands of firebase and it stays only the last step which is when i connect to firebase from the computer i must found the temperature.
Anyone can help me with this? Thanks.

> Copy from comment:  I cant copy all the code here because its too long :

```
import os, glob, time, calendar, json  
from urllib.request import urlopen 

while True: 
    url = 'projetfindetude-4dae9.firebaseio.com/database.json' 
    postdata = { 'datetime': str(calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())), 'sensorId': "1", 'tempRecord': str(read_temp()) } 

    req = Request(url) 
    req.add_header('Content-Type','application/json') 
    data = json.dumps(postdata) 
    response = urlopen(req,data)
```

> the error:
>
> ```
> req = request(url) NameError: name 'request' is not defined
> ```

Comment: Read [urllib.request.Request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement `from urllib.request import urlopen` imports only `urlopen`. If you want to call `Request`, then you need to either specifically import `Request`, or import the whole `urllib.request` module (and then call `Request` as `urllib.request.Request`).

Comment: Thank you for your help :)
But there is another Error with urlopen.


module = self._original_import(*args, **kw)
ImportError: No module named 'urlopen'